# UMD support throughout our JavaScript plugins means

Tags: javascript, plugins

In Bootstrap 4, they are going to implement "UMD support throughout our JavaScript plugins."

UMD stand for?

Answer (score 0):

UMD stands for [Universal Module Definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)